# Can't see my character

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Ever since I let someone at the College of Winterhold cast a spell on me I have not been able to see my character. I'm on Xbox Skyrim

Comment: I  know on Skyrim you can let a female Dark Elf cast a spell on you, but that simply makes everything green for a few in-game hours.

Comment: Do you have a picture of your character? Is it simply happening because of a green filter? The more details you give us, the better answer you will receive.

Comment: Sorry. I'm new at all this. But there was some girl at the college that wanted to practice Magic on me the first time it did something I don't even remember then eventually I went back she tried it again and from that point forward I have not been able to see my character

Comment: Is everything green?

Comment: No that was the first time she practiced on me

Comment: This time after she did it my character disappeared and she said something to the effect of oh let's not tell anyone about this or something like that

Comment: Where you turned into an animal? Then it is best to simply reload a save before you let her experiment on you.

Comment: A screen shot would help alot!!!!

Comment: I'm playing on an old Xbox that is not connected to anything except the television. I don't think a screenshot would make any difference anyway. You simply cannot see my character no matter what buttons I push

Comment: Then load back to a save before you let her experiment on you!

Comment: Got that. Just wondering if there was a way to fix it. Have a nice day

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so after reading some up on the quest, there actually is no way to fix this! [Here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Brelyna%27s_Practice) is my source. (Go to the bottom of the page, under "Bugs")

To be completely honest, just reload an older save and hope that works!